# Web API with json as a parameter

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Im working with asp.net MVC4, trying to implement some Web API with HTTP Post actions.
Some of these actions require Json as a parameter, here is the signature of my method:

```
 [HTTPPost]
  public void notificationValueChanged(JObject data)
    {
        dynamic json = data;
        string boxSN = json.boxSN;
        string nodeID = json.nodeID;
        string propertyName = json.propertyName;
        string instanceId = json.instanceId;
        string propertyKey = json.propertyKey;
        string newValue = json.newValue;
        DateTime timestamp = json.timestamp;

        // ....

   }
```

Now the problem is that when I tested my web api throught https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn/related , 
I got an error saying that my parameter can not be loaded as Json file.

However when working with my web API locally using ajax, it does work fine. But after i deploy it my work on IIS server , and tried to access to this web api from an other server ( exp ACS ) , it doesn't get the data entered type .

Any recommendation on how to solve this problem will be appreciated.